# Responsive canvas in <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm attempting to make a draggable list (horizontal) with canvas-elements in each listitem.
I've got a working concept on it here: https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/zBmRVk

What I need help with is making it responsive.
I've already tried by manipulating the widths and heights like this:

```
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

But all that does is making the list vertical and placing the second chart on top of the first. What I want is clearly to have the chart "to the right" of the first.

**I'm also** a bit confused on why the second chart is slightly higher than the first; I don't seem to be able to see why it would be higher in the .js code.

Any clues?

EDITS:

**NOTE**: I know the codepen might not be following correct coding-standard; keep in mind it's a proof of concept - not the finalized code!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it myself by adding a surrounding section and divs:

**CSS:**

```
#slider { 
  width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul { 
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.list-element {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-5">
              <div id="slider"> 
                <ul>
                        <div class="element">
                           <li><canvas id="programming"> </canvas>
                           </li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="element">
                           <li>
                           <canvas id="design"> </canvas>
                           </li> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="element">
                           <li> <canvas id="theory"> </canvas> </li>
                       </div>
                   </ul> 
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</section>
```